# характеристики категорий

Tags: mysql, sql

Один наверно из самых популярных вопросов :). Пытаюсь сделать доску объявлений . Хочу сделать что бы при добавлении категории можно было забивать в БД характеристики (цвет, объем, память, тип, модель и тд...)для данной категории. Что бы потом при выборе категории в подачи объявления можно было заполнять характеристики данного товара. Типа как на [olx.ua](http://olx.ua/post-new-ad/)
Сильно не критикуйте, исключительно делаю для собственной практики. 
Набросал следующую структуру БД

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads`.`categories` (
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parend_id` INT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `name` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `alias` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads`.`ads` (
  `ads_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NULL,
  `created_at` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ads_id`),
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads`.`properties` (
  `property_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`property_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads`.`property_value` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `property_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads`.`property_category` (
  `property_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL,
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads`.`pvalue_ads` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `ads_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `value_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Хотелось бы выслушать мнения недоставка такого подхода.

- был вырезан код внешних ключей для меньшего объема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формально - все логично и верно - как по учебнику. Но, на практике, избыточная нормализация - не совсем оптимальный подход. Я-бы не стал разделять `properties`,  `property_value` и `property_category` и постарался-бы обойтись всего 3-ми таблицам - `cats`, `props` и `cats_props_rel`.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. А что собой представляет таблица cats_props_rel ? Только category_id и props_id ? Просто не пойму где тогда хранить варианты характеристики.

Comment: `cats_props_rel : {id int autoincrement, cat_id int, prop_id int}`

`cat_id` - ссылка на ID из таблицы категорий

`prop_id` - ссылка на ID из таблицы характеристик 

варианты характеристик хранятся в таблице `props` под уникальным ID

Comment: а значения характеристик тогда получается нужно хранить в самой таблице характеристики ? Типа так: _props {id int AI, name varchar (100), value varchar(255)}_ . То есть значения хранить в одном поле, через какой то к примеру разделитель.